# How to change the origin of the canvas to the center?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to html and JavaScript, I am writing a program dealing with points and lines in a coordinate system, but as you know the origin of a canvas for html5 is at the upper corner, I want to build a coordinate system with its origin at the center of the canvas, I have tried the translate method and use the following method to print where my mouse is (ideally, I want it to display 0 : 0 when the mouse is at the center of the canvas), but it does not seem to work:

```
var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas1, evt);
mouseX = mousePos.x;
mouseY = mousePos.y;
var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
writeMessage(document.getElementById("canvas_prime_coor"), message);

function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.font = '18pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top};
}
```

Comment: [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#translate())

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the *coordinate* system you can use the `translate()` method. However, transformation of the context does not affect the mouse coordinates which are bounded to the *element* itself so you need to keep track of this separately.

You will have to manually track the translation and compensate for the mouse coordinates:

```
var transX = canvas.width * 0.5,
    transY = canvas.height * 0.5;

context.translate(transX, transY);
```

The problem now is that you deal with two different positions:

a) The actual mouse position relative to *element*
b) The coordinate *needed* to be correct for the *context*

If you translate and then use the mouse position, and you translate to center the following would happen:

Lets say your mouse coordinate was 30,30. If you use this coordinate on a translated context the graphics would end up at transX + 30, transY + 30 which is not what you want.

To compensate for this you need to keep track of current translation and subtract that to the mouse coordinates:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left - transX,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top - transY
    };
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/ARp2L/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: You may want to flip the y axis so up is increasing with context.scale(1, -1);