# How do I put the origin of the canvas in the center

Tags: fabricjs, transcrypt

I am trying to write simple turtle graphics for my [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org/) Python to JavaScript compiler. To be compatible with the CPython Turtle module, I need carthesian coordinates, i.e. the origin must be in the center of the canvas. Is there any way I can achieve that without using a separate coordinate system myself and transforming them for each object in my own code.

I've seen that for individual objects I can use centerX and centerY to center their reference point inside such object. But I couldn't find an example of putting the origin in the middle of the canvas.

The solution given in [How to change the origin of the canvas to the center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373975/how-to-change-the-origin-of-the-canvas-to-the-center) works, but looks somewhat artificial, as I would to compensate the mouse position for this translation. Also it gives a strange "doubling" of some line segments, probably due to an offset. If a translate the coordinates in my own code, the doubling is absent. Both translations add integers.

[image: Translation using canvas context]

Translation using canvas context, some lines double. Code:

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__ (self):
        self._canvas = __new__ (fabric.Canvas ('canvas', {'backgroundColor': 'lightgray'}))
        self._canvas.onWindowResize = self.resize
        self._canvas.onWindowDraw = self.draw

        self._context = self._canvas.getContext ('2d')
        self._context.translate (self._canvas.getWidth () / 2, self._canvas.getHeight () / 2)

        self.reset ()

    def reset (self):
        self._canvas.clear ()   
        self.pensize (1)
        self.color ('black')
        self.down ()
        self._position = [0, 0]
        self._heading = Math.PI / 2
```

[image: Translation in my application code]

Translation in my application code, as it should look.
Code:

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__ (self):
        self._canvas = __new__ (fabric.Canvas ('canvas', {'backgroundColor': 'lightgray'}))
        self._canvas.onWindowResize = self.resize
        self._canvas.onWindowDraw = self.draw

        self._context = self._canvas.getContext ('2d')

        self.reset ()

    def reset (self):
        self._canvas.clear ()   
        self.pensize (1)
        self.color ('black')
        self.down ()
        self._position = [self._canvas.getWidth () / 2, self._canvas.getHeight () / 2]
        self._heading = Math.PI / 2
```

Comment: I found out SVG is much more suitable for this job, and used it for the Turtle module. It's path statement maps closely to turtle moves, and when you zoom in, lines stay smooth. In general anti-aliasing is much better.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid de "doubling" effect you can try this:

```
self._context.translate (round(self._canvas.getWidth () / 2), round(self._canvas.getHeight () / 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've abandoned the canvas in favor of SVG. And the result is quite pleasing: http://www.transcrypt.org/live/turtle_site/turtle_site.html , especially the mandala demo.