# I need to "redefine" Canvas coordinates, so the center is {0,0}

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, coordinates

I have some coordinates which i want to display as points, but they are in the negative range. I need to redefine the center of the canvas, so it won't be `{width/2, height/2}`, but it will be truly the `{0,0}`, or origo of the canvas.

I tried flipping scales and translating coordinates so far, but it just skews the coordinates. If what I mentioned in the title cannot be done, i need some tips to overcome this problems, since im not that great with this kind of stuff.

Since it's coordinates of a game's map, i would like to see the exact copy of that.

Comment: Do math on your real coordinates?

Comment: If you need to draw `{0,0}` at `{width/2, height/2}`, add `{width/2, height/2}` to your point.

Comment: transforming coordinates just skews them totally, first thing i came up with is a simple mirror transformation by multiplying every coordinate by -1, but then they wont get drew on the canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the origin of the canvas to the center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373975/how-to-change-the-origin-of-the-canvas-to-the-center)